# How do I sum columns that contains certain item_id in the column with corresponding status = pending

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

This is my table looks like:

```
id | Prs Id | Amount | Status | Item Id|
----------------------------------------
1  |   10   |   200  |pending | 5      |
2  |   10   |   300  |pending | 7      |
3  |   10   |   400  |pending | 9      |
4  |   10   |   100  |received| 6      |
5  |   10   |   200  |received| 8      |
6  |   10   |   300  |received| 3      |
7  |   10   |   200  |pending | 5      |
8  |   10   |   300  |pending | 7      |
9  |   10   |   400  |pending | 9      |
10 |   10   |   100  |received| 6      |
11 |   10   |   200  |received| 8      |
12 |   10   |   300  |received| 3      |
```

How can I get the sum `amount` from a specific `item_id` that also has a `status` of `pending`?

Comment: select Item_ID, sum(Amount) from yourtable where Item_ID in (5, 9) and Status = 'Pending' group  by Item_ID.  Is that wat you are asking?

Comment: @VasanthSundaralingam post it as answer. Also, `'Pending'` should have lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the query for that:

```sql
select sum(Amount)
  from TableName
 where Status = 'pending'  
   and Item_ID = 7
```